# pass a variable to move a bullet at angle

Tags: javascript, canvas, angle

so basically I am currently implementing shooting at cursor mechanic into my game. I have a mousemove eventListener to check for mouse coordinates and to calculate the angle at what my character should shoot. I just need to pass the final vx and vy variables from my handleMouse function to my update function, but I can't figure out how. It's probably going to be very simple solution, but I can't get my head around it since I am pretty new to programming. Thank you very much.

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouse, false);

function getMousePosition(e){
    var x, y;
    x = e.clientX - backgroundCanvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    y = e.clientY - backgroundCanvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    return {x:x, y:y};
}

function handleMouse(e){    
    var pos = getMousePosition(e);
    posx = pos.x; //mouse x position
    posy = pos.y; //mouse y position

    var delta = {x: posx - player.x, y: posy - player.y}; //y2 - y1, x2 - x1
    var angle = Math.atan2(delta.y, delta.x) ; 

    var vx = Math.cos(angle - (Math.PI/2)) * game.bulletSpeed;
    var vy = Math.sin(angle - (Math.PI/2)) * game.bulletSpeed;
    return {vx:vx, vy:vy};
}

function update(){
    //move bullets - this is where I need to pass the vx and vy variables
    var vector = handleMouse(e); // this is probably wrong
    vx = vector.vx;
    vy = vector.vy;

    for (i in game.bullets){
        game.bullets[i].x -= vx;
        game.bullets[i].y -= vy;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would help, assuming that you directly want to pass `vx` and `vy` variables from `handleMouse` method to `update` method.

```
function handleMouse(e){    
    var pos = getMousePosition(e);
    posx = pos.x; //mouse x position
    posy = pos.y; //mouse y position

    var delta = {x: posx - player.x, y: posy - player.y}; //y2 - y1, x2 - x1
    var angle = Math.atan2(delta.y, delta.x) ; 

    var vx = Math.cos(angle - (Math.PI/2)) * game.bulletSpeed;
    var vy = Math.sin(angle - (Math.PI/2)) * game.bulletSpeed;

    //call update method
    update(vx, vy);

    return {vx:vx, vy:vy};
}
```

and the `update` method

```
function update(vx, vy){   
    for (i in game.bullets){
        game.bullets[i].x -= vx;
        game.bullets[i].y -= vy;    
    }
}
```

Comment: what does angle - (Math.PI/2) mean on this?

Comment: @NeonWarge, Good question, but I guess you are better off asking this question from vit libovicky.  -It’s been while since I’ve played action packed games such as this one :-)  Plus to be honest I’m no expert on geometry (although at the moment I wish I was)

I think the angle reflects the change between player’s new and old position after Math.atan2 function has been applied but about the Math.PI/2 part I’m not sure. I did run some tests using JSFiddle though: https://jsfiddle.net/p1dhsrd6/1/

Answer (score 0):

In handleMouse() you don't need to return some coordinates to the event listener, you need to call update() with the coordinates. Use function parameters to pass info to other functions. Variables you define in functions only exist in that scope and are lost once you leave that function.

```
function handleMouse(e) {
    ... calculate stuff ...
    update(vx, vy);
    // you can also pass an object as a parameter if you have more complex data:
    // update({vx: vx, vy: vy, name: 'foo', moreStuff: [1, 2, 3]});
}

function update(vx, vy) {
    ... calculate stuff ...
    game.bullets[i].x -= vx;
    game.bullets[i].y -= vy; 
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you guys, now the variables are passed to my update function, but the problem is that they change every time I move mouse and the bullet appears for just a fraction of second and then disappears and therefore it doesnt fly anywhere. Hopefully I will find a solution.

Comment: Ok, you will run into many more issues while writing your game - that's normal. If the question you asked here is solved, please consider accepting an answer.